# Drawing light scattered by a particle by different optics with different geometry

Tags: tikz-pgf, thesis, optical

Currently writing a PhD Thesis and I want to write in Latex. So, for figures, I would like to draw using the Tikz to make my thesis more presentable and smaller in size. I am very grateful if anyone could help me with tikz code on how to draw these figures. These figures illustrate light scattered by a particle in a particle counter with different optics geometry. Please help me with all these figures. Thank you in advance
[image: This is figures of a light scattered by a particle of a particle counter with different optics geometry]

Comment: So where are you stuck? I'd personally approach this with the Three Dimensional Drawing Library (`\usetikzlibrary{3d}`) and the scope options `[canvas is xy plane at z=0]`. See the corresponding chapter on Three Dimensional Drawing Library in the pgf/tikz manual http://mirror.koddos.net/CTAN/graphics/pgf/base/doc/pgfmanual.pdf It may also be helpful to have a look at the tikz 3d examples for other ideas: http://www.texample.net/tikz/examples/tag/3d/ for other approaches.

Answer (score 2):

This is maybe a start.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{patterns}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[ring at/.style={insert path={
    (#1,0) circle[y radius={sqrt(R*R-#1*#1)},x radius={a*sqrt(R*R-#1*#1)}]}},
    cone at/.style={ring at=#1,insert path={(#1,{sqrt(R*R-#1*#1)}) -- (0,0)
        -- (#1,-{sqrt(R*R-#1*#1)})}},
    pics/shell/.style={code={
    \tikzset{shell/.cd,#1}
    \def\pv##1{\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/shell/##1}} 
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\Rone}{sqrt(R*R-\pv{x1}*\pv{x1})}
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\Rtwo}{sqrt(R*R-\pv{x2}*\pv{x2})}
    %\pgfmathsetmacro{\AngleA}{acos()}
    \draw [pic actions] (\pv{x1},-\Rone)
    arc[start angle=-90,end angle=90,x radius=a*\Rone,y radius=\Rone]
    arc[start angle={acos(\pv{x1}/R)},end angle={acos(\pv{x2}/R)},radius=R]
    arc[start angle=90,end angle=-90,x radius=a*\Rtwo,y radius=\Rtwo]
    arc[start angle={-acos(\pv{x2}/R)},end angle={-acos(\pv{x1}/R)},radius=R]
    --cycle;
    \draw [pic actions] (\pv{x1},-\Rone)
    arc[start angle=270,end angle=90,x radius=a*\Rone,y radius=\Rone]
    arc[start angle={acos(\pv{x1}/R)},end angle={acos(\pv{x2}/R)},radius=R]
    arc[start angle=90,end angle=270,x radius=a*\Rtwo,y radius=\Rtwo]
    arc[start angle={-acos(\pv{x2}/R)},end angle={-acos(\pv{x1}/R)},radius=R]
    --cycle;
    }},declare function={R=4;a=0.1;},shell/.cd,x1/.initial=1,x2/.initial=2
    ]
  \begin{scope}
   \draw circle[radius=R];
   \draw [cone at=2];
   \pic[pattern=north east lines]{shell={x1=2.75,x2=3}};
  \end{scope}
  \begin{scope}[xshift=9cm]
   \draw circle[radius=R];
   \draw [cone at=-3];
   \draw[rotate=45] [cone at=2];
   \pic[rotate=45,pattern=north east lines]{shell={x1=2.75,x2=3}};
  \end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]